# Open Watcom error E1127 "Type required in parameter list"

Tags: c, watcom

I have a header with the following style of declarations:

```
extern struct xvimage *allocimage(char * name, int32_t rs, int32_t cs, int32_t ds, int32_t t);
extern struct xvimage *allocmultimage(char * name, int32_t rs, int32_t cs, int32_t ds, int32_t ts, int32_t nb, int32_t t);
etc...
```

Trying to compile it yields error E1127 "Type required in parameter list", immediately followed by E1022: Missing or misspelled data type near 'int32_t'.

I have already enabled implemented C99 extensions using the switch -za99. I am using the latest version of OpenWatcom (v1.9). I believe this project compiled nicely with gcc on linux.

What is wrong with these declarations? I don't even understand the error message. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `int32_t` type is defined in the `<stdint.h>` header, so make sure that one is included at the top of your header file.

Comment: Interestingly, when I tried to #define int32_t long, I got an error about conflict with some OW's standard header. Meanwhile, I installed MinGW, and it choked on the same line. Including stdint.h solves the problem for both compilers.